# Какой знак препинания поставить?

Tags: пунктуация

"Боль()дайте мне забыть это". Какой знак?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть 3 варианта, я бы предпочла первый.

Боль...дайте мне забыть это.

Боль - дайте мне забыть это.

Боль, дайте мне забыть это.